# DRF dynamic choices depend on current user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, choicefield

is there any way to make choices dynamically depend on current user
something like that:

```
class RideSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    provider_username = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=request.user.providers)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the choices during in the constructor. The following code show the idea. You can pass the request via context https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context

```
class RideSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    provider_username = serializers.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields["provider_username"].choices = request.user.providers
```